# getting Missing Template error while creating a new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> Missing template admin/citizens/create, admin/application/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder, :rabl]}. Searched in: * "/Users/aa/Sites/Active Shehri/activeshehri-mongo/app/views" * "/Users/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@activeshehri/gems/wiselinks-1.2.1/app/views" * "/Users/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@activeshehri/gems/rails_admin-0.6.6/app/views" * "/Users/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@activeshehri/gems/kaminari-0.16.1/app/views" * "/Users/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@activeshehri/gems/devise_invitable-1.5.5/app/views" * "/Users/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@activeshehri/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.2/app/views" * "/Users/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@activeshehri/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"

.....here is the code

```
= form_for [:admin, @user] do |f|
  .row
    .col-lg-6
      .panel
        .panel-heading Edit Landmark
        .panel-body
          .form-group
            = f.label :first_name
            = f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control'
          .form-group
            = f.label :last_name
            = f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control'
          .form-group
            = f.label :email
            = f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control'
          .form-group
            = f.label :gender
            = f.text_field :gender, :class => 'form-control'
          .form-group
            = f.label :contact_no
            = f.text_field :contact_no, :class => 'form-control'
          .form-group
            = f.label :address
            = f.text_field :address, class: 'form-control'
        = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-submit btn-lg pull-right'
        = link_to "Back", admin_home_user_panel_path, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-submit btn-lg pull-left'
```

Comment: use redirect_to or render  once object is saved in your create action. because you do not have create.html.erb

Comment: Are you sure you have create.html in your app/views/admin/citizens folder

Comment: Already using redirect_to admin_home_user_panel_path

Comment: share your create action

Comment: I don't have creat.html as I think after using "redirect_to admin_home_user_panel_path" it must work fine.

Comment: def create
    user = User.new(new_params)
    if user.save
      redirect_to admin_home_user_panel_path
    end
  end

Comment: do u have you have validations in place. if so i think you are getting error when you try to create invalid user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add else part to handle when user is not saved

```
def create
  @user = User.new(new_params) 
  if @user.save 
    redirect_to admin_home_user_panel_path
  else
    #do render or redirect_to
  end 
end
```

Comment: yes, when i put the else part in code it redirect to new page. but it creating my user why not saving it? why @user.save not working?

Comment: May be you have some validation errors. Use render in else part. So missing template error is gone now

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you don't have a file called `create.html.erb` in your `views/admin/citizens` folder.

In Rails, if you don't tell it to redirect or render a specific template at the end of a Controller method, it infers a template to render instead, so:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.create(name: params[:name])
  end
end
```

If the create method is run here, a user will be created and then Rails will try to render the template `views/users/create.html.erb`. Typically, you will not have a template with that name - you would probably do something like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.create(name: params[:name])
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end
end
```

Or:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.create(name: params[:name])
    render :awesome_template
end
```

It's all here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions